# Azure Data factory pipeline varied execution times

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

We have about 190 hourly usage files that need to arrive in the data lake in a 24 hour period before we can kick off our pipeline which starts off with an analytics activity. We have had this pipeline run on a scheduler on an estimated time of when we expect all files to have arrived but doesn't always happen so we would need to re-run the slices for the missing files.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this and not have the pipeline on a schedule and have it triggered by the event that all files have arrived in the datalake.

TIA for input!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Event Trigger when a new blob is created (or deleted). We do this in production with a logic app, but data factory V2 appear to support it now as well. The benefit is that you don't have to estimate the proper frequency, you can just execute when necessary.

NOTE: there is a limit to the number of concurrent pipelines you can have executing, so if you dropped all 190 files into blob storage at once, you may run into resource availability issues.